# The state of multiple components store in an array is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, use-reducer

I have a single component that will be injected into the DOM on every onClick event. I intend to manage both the future and previous state of the component irrespective of its number injected into the page. Also, I intend to make each instance of the component to be unique.

This is the component:

```js
const Paper = ({ elemCount, handleClick, showAddBtn, showDeleteBtn }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="paper">
            <div>
              <input placeholder="section title" name={`title_${elemCount}`} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <textarea name={`body_${elemCount}`} cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="actionBtn">
              {showAddBtn && (
                <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>Add Section</button>
              )}
              {showDeleteBtn && (
                <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>Delete Section</button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
```

Using an array, I decided to store each instance of the component in an array and then render multiple components stored in the array. I am trying to keep track of all the instances of this component that will be automatically created by the user on every button click.

The issue I notice is that state change does not affect the previous component(s) stored in the array. I really want the previous state of the previous component store to change. This is because I want to hide the **add button** on the previous component(s) and only display the delete button. I want the add button and delete button to be displayed on the latest instance of the component added to the page.

The entire code is as follows:

```
import { useReducer, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Paper from "./Paper";

const Form = () => {

  const defaultCount = 1;
  const [elementCount, setElementCount] = useState(defaultCount);
  const [showAddBtn, setAddBtn] = useState(true);
  const [showDeleteBtn, setDeleteBtn] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "append" });
  }, [showAddBtn, showDeleteBtn]);

  //   const extraOption = <Paper />;
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setElementCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    setAddBtn((prevState) => !prevState);
    setDeleteBtn((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "append":
        return [
          ...state,
          <Paper
            key={elementCount}
            handleClick={handleClick}
            elemCount={elementCount}
            showAddBtn={true}
            showDeleteBtn={true}
          />,
        ];
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }

  // const [multipleElem, setMultipleElement] = useState([]);

  const [multipleElem, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  console.log(multipleElem);

  return (
    <form action="#" method="post">
      {multipleElem}
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setAddBtn(false);
        }}
        type="submit"
      >
        Submit Now
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Please I am really new to react; I am just trying to get my hands dirty with this framework. A solution/recommendation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is very weird to store a component instance in state.  You should store the props instead.  Loop through the array of props and create a `Paper` for each one.

Comment: When you add `Paper` element to the state, you create an instance with certain props and **those prop values will never change**

Comment: [Is this what you want?](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-remove-form-elements-w1g6w?file=/src/App.jsx)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for contributing. I am grateful. Since it was my first react project, I didn't understand that. Out of curiosity, I contacted a friend who gave me exactly this explanation. So the issue was solved. I thought component can be managed also in state - 